# Is there a word to decsribe what appears to be social ignorance?

Tags: expressions, american-english

I am trying to come up with a way to describe a person that denies they have a problem due to the large number of people in society that follow the same beliefs.

Very confusing.. stay with me here.

I am working on an English essay about how technology is impacting relationships and causing social disconnect between general conversation skills. I am trying to describe how a person believes that they don't have an issue or that they aren't "addicted" to technology just because they see everyone else doing the same thing, when all those people they are observing are in the same situation.

I guess what I am looking for is kinda like social denial perhaps?

Any words help to clarify what I am trying to explain?

Comment: try **conformist**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like **confirmation bias**

In psychology and cognitive science, confirmation bias (or confirmatory bias) is a tendency to search for or interpret information in a way that confirms one's preconceptions, leading to statistical errors.

(http://www.sciencedaily.com/terms/confirmation_bias.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. The word is snobbery.

It's a derivative of the word snob, which is defined here (2):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/snob

Despite popular belief, a measure of healthy snobbery can be beneficial to everyone. It all depends on the situation. The trick is to remain polite at all times. Like this:

> "I'm sorry, I've never heard of those *apps* ... apps, aren't they?
>   ... No, I don't know what the word means. I'm a Wagnerite."
>   "You're a *what*?"
>   "A Wagnerite."

Et voila!

Answer (score 0):

Some phrases that convey what you are looking for.
"herd mentality" would be one choice, along with "safety of the herd".

The herd mentality of technology addicts, seeing their own reflection in those around them, texting away, leaves them oblivious to their own social ineptitude in having what used to be considered normal human conversation.

I am not aware of a *single* word that easily conveys this meaning in English.
Perhaps the German language, which gave us "schadenfraude", may have a single perfect word for this.